# Skip to next UItextField

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield

I have some UITextfields in a UItableView. the textfields have been subclassed in a UITableViewCell that I have created. I would lke to know how to progress down to the next cell in its respective row after the return key is pressed on the keyboard.

So if the user was to start on width, they would continue down the width colum, or if they wanted to enter height each time they hit enter they would continue down that column.

currently whats happening is if i use the width colum, it works fine but if i select a height UItextField after hitting enter it jumps over to the next width cell.

This is my code for detecting the return key.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [[self.view viewWithTag:textField.tag+1] becomeFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

and this is what my tableview of cells looks like.

[image]

For more information this is how I add the custom celltextfields to  UItextfield.

```
NSString *widthString = [currentFinishingDictionary objectForKey:@"w"];
    if ((NSNull *) widthString != [NSNull null]) {
        cell.widthTexField.text = widthString;
        cell.widthTexField.delegate = self;
        cell.widthTexField.tag = indexPath.row;
    } else {
        cell.widthTexField.text = @" ";
        cell.widthTexField.delegate = self;
        cell.widthTexField.tag = indexPath.row;
    }

    NSString *heightString = [currentFinishingDictionary objectForKey:@"h"];
    if ((NSNull *) heightString != [NSNull null]) {
        cell.heightTextField.text = heightString;
        cell.heightTextField.delegate = self;
        cell.heightTextField.tag = indexPath.row;
    } else {
        cell.heightTextField.text = @" ";
        cell.heightTextField.delegate = self;
        cell.heightTextField.tag = indexPath.row;
    }
```

Comment: does a single cell contain 1 width textfield and 1 height textfield?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have set tag to `UITextField`

You should try in this way:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    //[[self.view viewWithTag:textField.tag+1] becomeFirstResponder];
    // Get here you cell seleted Refrecne
      id obj = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:textField.tag+1];

      if([obj isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
        UITextField *nextField = (UITextField*)obj
         [nextField becomeFirstResponder];
     } 
    return YES;
}
```

Or you can use [ELCTextFieldCell](https://github.com/B-Sides/ELCTextFieldCell)

It contents UITextField and UILabel in one cell. You can customizr as per your need.

Comment: obj is returning nil in this instance. coudl be cause I subclassed UItableViewCell? also I would use ELCTextFieldcell however I am commited to the UITavleview because of other views as well as the complexity of the tables themselves.. there is alot more to them than just these two textfields. also performacne wise UITabeViews are awesome when your subclassing the cells.

Comment: If `obj` is nil. Then you should check at are you giving exact tag value or not? Make sure that you are able to get correct cell instance when user tap on UITextField. If there are lot thing in UITableView then better to go with different cell Identifier.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
   - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
    {


UITableViewCell *cell = [self.myTableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: textField.tag+1 inSection:0]];
UITextField *tf = (UITextField*)[cell viewByTag:textField.tag+1]
[tf becomeFirstResponder];
        return YES;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue might be in the way the tags are assigned to the UITextFields.

Please check if the tag values are actually what you have assumed.

Comment: I am assigning them both the indexpath.row number for their tag which s cauing the problem. Im not sure how else to do it.

Comment: actually.. if i add 0.5 to the install tags it should work i htink.. nope.

Comment: I guess this means that there are two TextFields having the same tag.If this is the case you can consider giving width text fields number 100,101.102 .. etc and the height fields 1000,1001,1002,1003 .. etc. i.e. add extra 100 or 1000 while setting the tags. It might solve your issue.

Comment: yes. that might i would have to go or a larger number as so far i have had up to 800 textfields at one point..could be alot more or alot less... but that just feels lke abit of a ugly way to do it..

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
      [yourtextfield resignFirstResponder];
      // save state, etc if necessary
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyCell * cell = (MyCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    self.selectedField = cell.tf; // cell.tf is a UITextField property defined on MyCell
    [yourtextfield becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using collectionView instead of tableview, collection views design can be made similar to the image you added and you can add one textfield in one cell and then make first responder for width text field by doing this

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
if ( [tableView.dataSource tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0] > tag + 2)
        CustomCell *cell = [self.myTableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: textField.tag+2 inSection:0]];

        [cell.textField becomeFirstResponder];

}
```

If you wanna still persist with this design then you can do this

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{

     int xPosition = (int)textField.frame.origin.x;

     CustomCell *cell = [self.myTableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: textField.tag+1 inSection:0]];

     if((int)cell.textField1.x == xPosition)
     {
          [cell.textField1.x becomeFirstResponder];

     }
    else
     {
          [cell.textField2.x becomeFirstResponder];
     }
```

}

Code is not compiled. Only logic is written.Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your assigning tag values as below that may help you.

```
NSString *widthString = [currentFinishingDictionary objectForKey:@"w"];
    if ((NSNull *) widthString != [NSNull null]) {
        cell.widthTexField.text = widthString;
        cell.widthTexField.delegate = self;
        cell.widthTexField.tag = indexPath.row;
    } else {
        cell.widthTexField.text = @" ";
        cell.widthTexField.delegate = self;
        cell.widthTexField.tag = indexPath.row;
    }

    NSString *heightString = [currentFinishingDictionary objectForKey:@"h"];
    if ((NSNull *) heightString != [NSNull null]) {
        cell.heightTextField.text = heightString;
        cell.heightTextField.delegate = self;
        cell.heightTextField.tag = indexPath.row + 2000;
    } else {
        cell.heightTextField.text = @" ";
        cell.heightTextField.delegate = self;
        cell.heightTextField.tag = indexPath.row + 2000;
    }
```

Now your textfields tag looks like as below and may work as you desired.

```
0 2000
1 2001
2 2002
3 2003
4 2004
.. ........
```

Now your method work properly but need to think other idea as well because this will wrong when you have 2000 cells.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    // i.e. textField.tag == 6 then next 6 + 1 == 7
    // i.e. textField.tag == 20006 then next 2006 + 1 == 2007
    [[self.view viewWithTag:textField.tag+1] becomeFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```